# PHP Regex - find between two characters (keeping last character)

Tags: php, regex

Trying to help grab unique emails for a contest and have a few people using the gmail + symbol trick to get around it. I'm trying to get a clean way to filter the email so it removes everything in between the + and @ symbol so that:

> tester+dn2934u2@gmail.com

becomes:

> tester@gmail.com

So far I have:

```
\+(.*?)\@
```

which removes the + and @ symbols. Is there a way (and I'm sure there is) to tell regex to keep the @ character so I don't need to re-add it, replace it, or some other trick?

http://regex101.com/r/zM8sT3

Comment: There is no need to escape the `@` with a `\\` - it is not a metacharacter.

Comment: Just so you know this (the +) is not unique to gmail. One thing that is fairly unique to gmail is periods. You can put a period anywhere in your email and it's valid. So if your email is johndoe@gmail.com you can also use john.doe@gmail.com - so you might want to check for those too as "cheats".

Comment: It doesn't mean they are cheats tho. It can very well be that there are really people with similar emails...

Comment: In addition to @Jessica's comment it might be worth it to read [this blog post about validating e-mail](http://davidcel.is/blog/2012/09/06/stop-validating-email-addresses-with-regex/?utm_source=buffer&utm_medium=twitter&utm_campaign=Buffer&utm_content=bufferdb46a).

Comment: @Anyone Except those two emails go to the exact same person. I think you misunderstand ;) If you have gmail, you can add a + and anything to your email, or add a dot anywhere, and it still comes to you. No one else can actually have that email.

Comment: @jazZRo That is a great blog post, but it doesn't handle this situation. That post is about validating that an email is valid, not that it is not also a valid version of another existing email. If he just sends an email to the person, they now have gotten the email twice, and can "confirm" twice. They can still cheat his system.

Comment: Yeah, thanks @jazZRo, I usually do the email activation method but like Jessica mentioned the client's just on me about people trying to take advantage of our '1 email entry per day' contest. While this certainly doesn't protect us from all exploits it will kill off enough of the problems we've been seeing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this:

```
\+[^@]+(?=@)
```

`(?=@)` is a lookahead assertion (its only a check) and means *followed by @*

Answer (score 3):

You can instead use a negated class:

```
\+[^@]*
```

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/eO1xB9)

Answer (score 2):

Just include the @ into the capture group:

```
\+(.*?@)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this to match everything but the @ symbol:

```
\+[^@]+
```

Full php code:

```
$mail = preg_replace('%\+[^@]+%', '', $mail);
```

Answer (score 0):

Put it within your selector?

```
eg \+(.*?\@)
```

Comment: You should make use of the code-formatting (and get used to this) to format your regex and thus make your answer better: either enclose it by two `\`` or put it into a new line preceeded by four spaces and a blank line. See the [help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

```
$email_stripped = preg_replace("/^(.+?)(\+.+)?(@.+)$/", "$1$3", $email);
```